# How do I launch a browser via terminal and have it open to a specific webpage on Mac?

Tags: macos

I'm working on a small personal project and could not find an answer anywhere. I'm brand new to the Mac world and so have 0 experience with BSD. I'm just looking to make it so that when a condition in an if statement is met (I know how to do that part) my default browser (Firefox) will open up to a specified webpage (ex $var = stackoverflow, opens to stackoverflow.com)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate on Super User: https://superuser.com/q/85151/691005

Answer (score 1):

Other users have already intimated the use of the `open` command using the syntax:

```
open /Path/To/browser.app http://example.com
```

which, in the case of *Firefox*, would resemble something like this:

```
open /Applications/Firefox.app https://stackoverflow.com
```

However, you can simplify this somewhat using the **`-a`** flag, which allows you to simply specify the name of the application you wish to open, like so:

```
open -a Firefox https://stackoverflow.com
```

Furthermore, since *Firefox* is your default browser, you can omit the application altogether.  URLs automatically get opened in the system's default browser:

```
open https://stackoverflow.com
```

which, in your case, will open the *Stack Overflow* website in *Firefox*, whilst on my system, it would open it up in *Safari* (my default browser).

You can also specify multiple URLs to open up multiple webpages at once:

```
open https://stackoverflow.com https://imdb.com https://youtube.com
```

which, on my system, opens each URL in a separate tab of the most recently active *Safari* window.  On yours, it will do a similar thing using *Firefox*, depending whether you've set the browser to open new pages in a separate window, or as a new tab in the same window, etc.

---

#### Scripting

Combining this with your `if...then` control statement, a simple bash script might look something like this:

```
?URL() { [[ -z "${@}" ]] && return 1 \
                         || printf '%s\n' "${@}" \
                          | egrep -ix 'stackoverflow|imdb|youtube' \
                          | printf 'https://%s.com\n' $(cat) \
                          | open $(cat); }
```

Then, running `?URL stackoverflow` would open **`https://stackoverflow.com`**, whereas running `?URL stackoverflow dropbox imdb` would open **`https://stackoverflow.com`** and **`https://imdb.com`**, but ***not*** **`https://dropbox.com`** (as it is not in the list of valid website matches).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `open` command, followed by the path to your browser in single quotes, followed by the URL to the site you want to open in single quotes. example

`open '/Applications/Google Chrome.app' 'http://youtube.com'`

Comment: awesome! thanks. will try when im back on my computer

Answer (score 0):

```
open '/Applications/Firefox.app/' 'http://www.du.ac.in'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.